# unterminated subpattern", re.error: missing ) at position 21

Tags: python, pandas

We created a program to parse log files then serve it with datasette. It runs fine on mac but when trying to run it on windows it fails with the error at the bottom. I have searched every unterminated subpattern question but have not been able to resolve the error.

The issue is the ( after jwa_procInfo_logs_ but I can't figure out how to fix it. I can remove the ( and the code will run, but it causes other issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
matcharchive = re.match(r"^.*jwa_procInfo_logs_([^" + os.path.sep + "]*)[.]zip", 
CONSOLE_ARGUMENTS.path)

raise source.error("missing ), unterminated subpattern",
re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 21
```

Comment: On Windows `os.path.sep` is \, which is an escape character in regex.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) when dealing with `str`s potentially holding characters of special meaning

```
matcharchive = re.match(r"^.*jwa_procInfo_logs_([^" + re.escape(os.path.sep) + "]*)[.]zip", 
CONSOLE_ARGUMENTS.path)
```